# Error "WARN No appenders could be found for logger" when opening IE in Selenium using Java

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

I am trying to open IE in through selenium 
Program :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
public class testnew
{

    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        System.out.println("hi");
        WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        //driver.close();
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> The output is displayed as below and after which it is error. can you
>   please let what is the mistake.

```
 Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
    2.44.0.0
    Listening on port 27138
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.17 seconds
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'TCCD3140', ip: '172.17.22.99', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:146)
    at testnew.main(testnew.java:11)
```

**System:**

64 bit

Comment: The exception stacktrace mentions that the protected mode settings should be same in all zones. Or there is a flakiness setting in capabilities which can be set to true (plz search for the exact name). Also you have not mentioned the path setting for internetexplorerdriver. Refer to this link - http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-run-webdriver-in-ie-browser

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help, i have changed the the settings to Protected mode and when i gave the path for the driver as 

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\Users\ashwinkumar\Desktop\Ashwin\Tests\ECX Automation\Softwares"); i get invalid "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )" kindly help.

Comment: Use \\ or / for path delimiter

Comment: U also need to add IEDriverServer.exe at the end of path

Answer (score 0):

The error which you spoke about :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
```

This is a `WARNING` and doesn't harm anyway. The reason you are seeing it is because you have configured the `Log4j Logger Module` Class with a program within the same project. As this particular script/program doesn't have the `Log4j Logger Module` configured so you see the error.

But your main error is :

```
SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

To get rid of this, you have to do :

- The **`IEDriverServer`** executable must be [downloaded](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and placed in your system.
- On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the **`Protected Mode`** settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be **`ON`** or **`OFF`**, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the **`Protected Mode settings`**, choose **`Internet Options...`** from the **`Tools menu`**, and click on the **`Security tab`**. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled **`"Enable Protected Mode"`**.
- Additionally, **`Enhanced Protected Mode`** must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. This option is found in the **`Advanced Tab`** of the **`Internet Options`** dialog.
- The **`Browser Zoom Level`** must be set to **`100%`** so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
- For Windows 10, you also need to set **`Change the size of text, apps, and other items`** to **`100%`** in **`Display settings`**.
- For IE 11 only, you will need to set a **`Registry Entry`** on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`**. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`**. Please note that the **`FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey`** may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a **`DWORD`** value named **`iexplore.exe`** with the value of **`0`**.
- Your own code with a simple tweak (adding the `setProperty("")` line ) will look like :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\IEDriverServer.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
  System.out.println("Google Home Page Opened");
  driver.quit();
  System.out.println("Driver Closed");
  ```
- When you provide the absolute path of the **`IEDriverServer.exe`** either use the single front slash `/` or use the escaped back slash `\\`.